# How to use custom_navigation_bar plugin in flutter to navigate to another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use this plugin as a bottom bar https://pub.dev/packages/custom_navigation_bar

and this is the bottom_bar I created as the below code:

```
import 'package:custom_navigation_bar/custom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:petty/configuration/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:petty/screens/categories_screen.dart';

class MyCustomBNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomBNavigationState createState() => _MyCustomBNavigationState();
}

class _MyCustomBNavigationState extends State<MyCustomBNavigation> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  // final pagesIndex = ;

  final List<Widget> _pagesIndex = <Widget>[
    IPetCatScreen(),
    IPetCatScreen(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBottomNavigationBar();
  }

  Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar() {
    return _buildBlurEffect();
  }

  Widget _buildBlurEffect() {
    return CustomNavigationBar(
      iconSize: 30.0,
      selectedColor: AppTheme.white,
      strokeColor: AppTheme.nearlyWhite,
      unSelectedColor: Colors.grey[600],
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      borderRadius: Radius.circular(20.0),
      blurEffect: true,
      opacity: 0.8,
      items: [
        CustomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.paw,
          ),
          selectedIcon: 
        ),
        CustomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.list,
          ),
        ),
        CustomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
          ),
        ),
        CustomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingCart,
          ),
        ),
        CustomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.userAlt,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      onTap: (index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
        });
      },
      isFloating: true,
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the home_screen I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:petty/configuration/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:petty/widgets/custom_navigation_bar/my_custom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:petty/widgets/my_shapes/my_custom_card.dart';

class IPetHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IPetHomeScreenState createState() => _IPetHomeScreenState();
}

class _IPetHomeScreenState extends State<IPetHomeScreen> {
  @override
  void deactivate() {
    // TODO: implement deactivate
    // ShareLocationScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(children: [
        MyCustomCard(colour: AppTheme.nearlyBlue),
        Positioned(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: MyCustomBNavigation(),
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

and let's day the Home Screen is the below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  MyCustomCard({
    @required this.colour,
    this.childCard,
    this.myOnTap,
  });

  final Color colour;
  final Widget childCard;
  final Function myOnTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: myOnTap,
      child: Container(
        child: childCard,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the second screen I want to navigate:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IPetCatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.green);
  }
}
```

and this is the below final result as the below image:

[image: screen]

Comment: What problem you are facing ?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I need to navigate to different screens using this plugin as I searched in this plugin how to use to navigate but didn't find any docs through this plugin I hope you could help me :D

Comment: Sure Just give mi a couple of min

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede thanks a lot for your support I am glad for that :)... just tyt :D

Comment: Please check my answer I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class MyCustomBNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyCustomBNavigationState createState() => _MyCustomBNavigationState();
    }

    class _MyCustomBNavigationState extends State<MyCustomBNavigation> {
      int _currentIndex = 0;
      @override
      void initState() {
         pageController = PageController(
          initialPage: _currentIndex,
          keepPage: true,
        );
         super.initState();
       }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            buildPageView(),
            Positioned(
                left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, child: _buildBottomNavigationBar()),
          ],
        );
      }

      Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar() {
        return _buildBlurEffect();
      }

      PageController pageController;

      final GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>> orderFormKey = GlobalKey();

      void pageChanged(int index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
        });
      }

      Widget buildPageView() {
        return PageView(
          key: orderFormKey,
          controller: pageController,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            pageChanged(index);
          },
          children: <Widget>[
          // You just need to replace your pages with this Container

            Container(child: Center(child: Text("First"))),
            Container(child: Center(child: Text("Second"))),
            Container(child: Center(child: Text("Third"))),
            Container(child: Center(child: Text("Fourth"))),
            Container(child: Center(child: Text("Fifth"))),
          ],
        );
      }

      Widget _buildBlurEffect() {
        return CustomNavigationBar(
          iconSize: 30.0,
          selectedColor: Colors.white,
          strokeColor: Colors.white12,
          unSelectedColor: Colors.grey[600],
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          borderRadius: Radius.circular(20.0),
          blurEffect: true,
          opacity: 0.8,
          items: [
            CustomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            ),
            CustomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
            ),
            CustomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.star)),
            CustomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
            ),
            CustomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
              setState(() {

                pageController.animateToPage(_currentIndex,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);
              });
            });
          },
          isFloating: true,
        );
      }
    }
```